# When is the reverse function on dedicated drywall screwdrivers useful?

Tags: drill

Is there any reason why the reverse function on a drywall screwdriver would be useful in certain situations?

On my Milwaukee drywall screwdriver, you have to apply downward pressure to disengage the clutch even when using the "reverse" function--which is pushing the opposite direction the screw wants to travel in order to unscrew itself. Basically, when I've tried using the reverse functionality, it's such a fine balance between high enough pressure to disengage the clutch and low enough pressure for the screw to actually come out and the end result is usually just burnt wood and a stripped hole from the screw spinning in place.

Comment: Maybe for the other side of the world they use drywall screws with left handed threads.

Comment: Is there something that makes them *only suitable for drywall* rather than *marketed mainly for drywall*? In many materials a spiral ratchet screwdriver can unscrew successfully, and that requires pushing against the screw.

Comment: I've never heard of being able to put enough pressure on a screw to rival the screw's upward strength when being turned counter clockwise.

Comment: @ChrisH The high RPMs (typically 4,000-6,000 RPM) and lower torque of dedicated drywall screwdrivers to make them lightweight makes them not suited to a lot of other tasks other than possibly driving screws for decking--I've heard anecdotally that decking is hard on dedicated drywall screwdrivers and can drastically shorten the usable life though. There are some that seem to dual market as "drywall/decking screwdrivers" and the ones I've seen seem to operate at a slightly reduced RPM (~2,500), and have a slightly higher torque.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor With fine threaded drywall screws and the tool's 6,000 RPMs, I'm easily able to drive the screws *in* to #2 southern pine studs with the screwdriver in reverse and the same amount of pressure I use to drive screws in will the tool in "forward".

Comment: @statueuphemism, that's interesting. They're not a mass market product here where drywall is not as common. Drill drivers are widely used and my dedicated power screwdriver is low speed, moderate torque and rarely used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've removed hundreds of screws with drywall guns over the years for various reasons (changes of plans, later access by subcontractors). Never has a screw stripped in the wood. You might ask yourself if you're using appropriate screws for the job. IMO, fine-thread screws are for metal framing.

One case where it's *not* particularly useful is when framing is missed behind drywall. Backing out a screw that's just set in gypsum doesn't work well. You usually end up pulling them with fingers or pliers.

My point is that the reverse function works just as expected despite the clutch action with what I consider to be proper screws set in solid material.

Answer (score 1):

Useful if you catch a mistake before driving the screw all the way, and costs very little to include in the tool's design... I haven't used one of these, but I suspect there may also be a way to temporarily disable the clutch.